# Numpy functions/methods without brackets explanation

Tags: python, numpy, methods, properties

I'm just trying to wrap my head around the syntax here:

```
# some data
import numpy as np
x = linspace(0, 1, 100)

x.sum()    # works with brackets
> 50.0

x.shape    # works without brackets
> (100,)

x.shape()  # fails with brackets
> TypeError
```

Why is it that some methods/functions have brackets while others don't?

Comment: sum is an integer, shape is a 1-element tuple.

Comment: `shape` isn't a method.

Comment: The ones with `()` are methods, the ones without `()` are properties or attributes.

Comment: shape is maybe a property then (a method in disguise)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access an attribute of your instance you really access a descriptor. There are three common cases:

- The descriptor returns a function like `x.sum`, that returns a bound function. Bound because the first argument to that function will be `x`. You obviously need to call `()` that function to give you an result.
- There are class and instance attributes, that simply return a value either saved in `x.__dict__` or `x.__class__.__dict__`. You don't need to call anything to get these. However `x.shape` isn't one of those!
- There are `properties`, when you access these it will **implicitly** call a method of your class. In general properties, say `x.something`, are equivalent to `x.__class__.something.fget(x)`. Seems weird but works ... sort of. The important thing here is that you normally don't need to call it directly `()` because you can just do `x.something`.

---

But that's technical, maybe the simpler explanation is better to remember:

- `sum` is a method. Methods should be called. To call a function or method you need the `()`.
- `shape` is a property (but could also be an attribute) and you don't need to call those! It could return a function as well but in this case it returns a `tuple` and you can't call a `tuple` instance.